# Bootstrap 4 row with two col's at the end of container

Tags: javascript, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have an angular project that has bootstrap 4.

The container has two rows. **I want one row to be at the bottom of the container always.**

I have tried `justify-content: flex-end;` , `bottom:0;` and other methods, but none seem to work.

Also note: the parent component just has `min-height: 100vh;` in it's CSS. (So the board is always full height)

Here is the code and to properly see the situation:

```
<div class="sight-slider bg-success">
    slider goes here <br>
    slider goes here <br>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 sight-info">
            <h2> Title of Sight </h2>
            <div class="sight-description">
                Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde culpa officiis obcaecati cupiditate 
                consequatur ducimus molestiae, quod quos incidunt! Laboriosam ab 
                modi nobis nesciunt voluptate eum tempora pariatur possimus et?
                Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde culpa officiis obcaecati cupiditate 
                consequatur ducimus molestiae, quod quos incidunt! Laboriosam ab 
                modi nobis nesciunt voluptate eum tempora pariatur possimus et?
            </div>
            <div class="sight-logic-info">
                Bla <br>
                Phone <br>
                Hours <br>
                Website
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row btn-controls"> <!-- THIS ROW I NEED AT BOTTOM -->
        <div class="col-3 bg-danger">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-exit">X</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-9 bg-warning">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-go">Go to location</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap has a few class built-in that can help.
You tell us you set `min-height:100vh` on the parent so i'll add this parent missing here and will use twice flex with `flex-direction:column` boostrap class : `.flex-column`.

To fill entire space, `flex:1;/* or only flex-grow:1; */` is required and a custom class is needed.

finally, `margin-top:auto` ,via `mt-auto` class, will push the buttons container all the way down to bottom if it needs to.

```css
/* custom class */

.min-h100vh {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.flex-1 {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class=" d-flex flex-column min-h100vh"><!-- flex boxe turned into a single column to minfill window -->
  <div class="sight-slider bg-success">
    slider goes here
  </div>
  <div class="container flex-1 d-flex flex-column "><!-- column again + fill entire space left -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 sight-info">
        <h2> Title of Sight </h2>
        <div class="sight-description">
          Lorem, ipsum dolor ...
        </div>
        <div class="sight-logic-info">
          Bla bla bla ...
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row btn-controls mt-auto"><!-- margin-top:auto; to go all the way down -->
      <!-- THIS ROW I NEED AT BOTTOM -->
      <div class="col-3 bg-danger">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-exit">X</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-9 bg-warning">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-go">Go to location</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

You can find the boostrap class about flex here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/  margin and padding here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/  , ...

Comment: I have added `flex-direction:column` to the parent container. Then I added the `flex-1 d-flex flex-column` and `mt-auto` to my elements. But it still hasn't pushed the row to the bottom. I will look into this more.

Comment: Fixed it ! Works great now. I didn't need to add anything to the parent component. Thank you very much @G-Cyr

Answer (score 0):

Since there are 2 items inside `.container` (`div.row` and `div.row.btn-controls`), you can set `flex`, `column` and justify as `space-between`, like this:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

So it should make that row stay at bottom.

Other possible solution depending on the situation:

As you mention `bottom: 0`. Also set `position: relative` to it. Or `position: absolute` and on its parent `position: relative` to make it as a reference.